# Dynamic data type in javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, asp.net-core

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strinng);
```

What would be the javascript code for this .NET code?

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
let object = JSON.parse(string);
```